# Look up/match values within the same dataframe column in R

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements

Given `data.frame(code=c(10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 40, 50), label=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"))`, I'd like `c("", "", "b", "b", "b", "", "", "", "")`.

If the value is not a multiple of 10, assign the label of the immediately previous multiple of 10 if it is listed. If the immediately previous multiple of 10 is not listed, assign blank. If the value is a multiple of 10, assign blank. (Unlike this dummy example, multiple sequences of non-multiples of 10 may occur in the data and the values may not be ordered.)

Ideally, I'd like to do this as a vector operation in base R, for speed and parsimony.

EDIT: I was trying to simplify my question as much as possible but maybe it was misleading so here is the final output I'm aiming for: `data.frame(code=c(10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 40, 50), label=c("a", "b", "b c", "b d", "b e", "f", "g", "h", "i"))`. That is: prepend the intermediate output to the label column.

Comment: Is there a correction required in your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at your expected output.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to clarify the language in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an overkill but seems to work :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  #arrange the data based on value
  arrange(code) %>%
  #Get closest multiple of 10
  mutate(multiple10 = floor(code/10) * 10,
         #If completely divisible by 10 assign label else NA
         result = ifelse(code %% 10 == 0, label, NA)) %>%
  #For each multiple of 10
  group_by(multiple10) %>%
  #fill NA by most recent non-NA in the group
  fill(result) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  #Turn NA to blank along with numbers which are completely divisible by 10
  mutate(result = replace(result, code == multiple10 | is.na(result), ''))

#  code label multiple10 result
#  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr> 
#1    10 a             10 ""    
#2    20 b             20 ""    
#3    21 c             20 "b"   
#4    22 d             20 "b"   
#5    23 e             20 "b"   
#6    31 f             30 ""    
#7    32 g             30 ""    
#8    40 h             40 ""    
#9    50 i             50 ""
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, but I need the result in vector form so I can concatenate it with existing label vector. I will update the OP to reflect this additional step.

Comment: I don't think you need too many changes in my current answer to implement that. Adding `result = paste0(result, label)` should do it.